# Convert numpy array to MemoryView object

Tags: arrays, numpy, memoryview

I'm trying to convert a numpy array to a `MemoryView` object because I have to communicate between two programs. The one can only handle NumPy arrays and the other only MemoryView objects.

Converting from MemoryView to numpy array is easily done by:

```
import numpy as np
MyNumpyArray=np.array(MyMemoryView)
```

But how do you convert from numpy array to MemoryView?

I found here: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memoryview.html That there's a PyMemoryView_FromObject(PyObject *obj) function, but I don't know how to call it without an example.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the other program a C program? If it's Python, you can just use `memoryview(np.array(...))`.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I think it is yeah, I'm talking to the GUI but I think it's C-based. Your solution and that of Grr worked as a charm! Strange that I couldn't find this simple solution online..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) is one of the built-in types and can simply be called as:

```
arr = np.random.rand(5,4)
view = memoryview(arr)
view
<memory at 0x12699c318>
```

Comment: Also `view[i]` can be used to index the `memoryview` object.

Answer (score 5):

Additionally to accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48214546/941531) providing another simple method to get memoryview out of Numpy array:

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow48213474#main.py)

```
a = np.arange(1, 9)
view = a.data
print(type(view)) # <class 'memoryview'>
```

In other words `.data` attribute of array variable gives exactly `memoryview`.